# What are the abbreviations most commonly used on the Internet?

Tags: abbreviations, internet

Every so often I see various abbreviations used on forums and blogs and whatnot, such as FYI (For Your Information) and AFAIK (As Far As I Know).

What other common abbreviations are there, and what are their meanings?

Comment: IMNSHO IHAA WIIGTE - In my not so humble opinion, I hate abbreviation abuse. Where is going to end?

Comment: @Ivo nice one... but you forgot an "it" in the long form ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Here are some that I've seen quite often (there are many more [here](http://www.alsindependence.com/Internet_Slang.htm)):

- AFAIC: As Far As I'm Concerned
- AFAIK: As Far As I Know
- AFAIR: As Far As I Recall
- AFK: Away From Keyboard
- ATM: At The Moment
- BSOD: Blue Screen Of Death
- BTDT: Been There, Done That
- BTW: By The Way
- FAQ: Frequently Asked Questions
- FTR: For The Record
- FWIW: For What It's Worth
- FYI: For Your Information
- GIGO: Garbage In, Garbage Out
- IANAL: I Am Not A Lawyer
- IIRC: If I Recall Correctly
- IMHO: In My Humble Opinion
- IMNSHO: In My Not So Humble Opinion
- IOW: In Other Words
- IRL: In Real Life
- LOL: Laughing Out Loud
- OOTB: Out Of The Box
- RTFM: Read The Manual
- TLA: Three Letter Acronym
- YMMV: Your Mileage May Vary

Comment: I'm quite partial to "IMPAO"... yes, I can be arrogant ;-D

Comment: Oh, and the F in RTFM has apparently been censored, when we all know that it stands for "Fine" ("Read The Fine Manual").  ;-)

Comment: @jae - I prefer the "F" to stand for "flimsy" since most of them (IME) never completely cover the topic I am looking for right then.

Comment: "LOL" can also stand for "lots of love", though it's certainly less common.

Comment: specifically to internet - AFK and IRL are also widely used.

Answer (score 5):

One I've seen only recently is

- tl;dr

which apparently means "too long; didn't read".

Comment: I've also seen tl;dnr for those who don't like to abbreviate their abbreviations

Comment: More info at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209439/what-does-tldr-mean-and-how-is-it-used

Answer (score 1):

WTF - What the F*** (or 'Why the face' - Modern Family. Phil: "I'm cool dad, that's my thang. I'm hip, I surf the web, I text. LOL: laugh out loud, OMG: oh my god, WTF: why the face")

Answer (score 1):

i've noticed the emergence of the letter "F" in common acronyms, added for color. i.e. BTFW (by the f-ing way), etc. @Kramii's answer includes my favorite: RTFM!