# Is tl;dr used very much outside of the computer programming community?

Tags: word-usage, contemporary-english

I read **tl;dr** a lot in computer articles. It is used to give a condensed version of a long report. (It may mean, "Too Long; Didn't Read.")

Is it safe to use that term or jargon in common writing outside the computer field, or should I use "Summary"?

Comment: Searching for tl;dr on this Q&A site returns 29 pages of uses.

Comment: It's internet slang, not confined to any one community (aside from the community of internet users).  There's probably no use for it, other than the standard usefulness of slang, i.e. as a shibboleth.

Comment: Related: [What does 'TL;DR' mean and how is it used?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209439/)

Comment: What do you mean by safe? If we don’t know where you live you will be safe from the retribution that this unnecessary and confusing abomination deserves. But ask yourself, why not just write English that will be comprehensible to all?

Answer (score 7):

tl;dr is internet slang. It did indeed originate as "too long; didn't read" and effectively still means that.

It's common enough outside of computing. But it's not in any way formal English. You shouldn't use it except in places where internet slang is acceptable. Appropriate synonyms are "summary" and "abstract".

**tl;dr - don't use it anywhere you wouldn't write 'LOL'**

Comment: That advice would mean that some people would feel empowered to use "tl:dr" almost anywhere (lol).